# I want screen resolution at particular width in css?

Tags: css, media-queries

I want red colour when my screen resolution is between 1250px to 1350px .
Below is my code:

```
    <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 1250px){
    .navigation .menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    background-color: red;    
     }
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: i think it took longer for you to make an account here and post a question, that it would've taken you to search the answer on google ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much magic. You pretty much just write down what you want to do:

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 1250px) and (max-width: 1350px){
.navigation .menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
background-color: red;    
 }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have write this in external stylesheet, and you can mention

`@media screen and (min-width:1250px) and (max-width:1350px)`

Request you to trying using this

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width:1250px) and (max-width:1350px){
    .navigation .menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    background-color: red;  
  }
}
</style>
```